# Sort two columns alphabetically by row and swap

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data frame with two columns with words. Every row I need the first column to have the alphabetically earlier one. For example. say I have this data frame with 3 rows.

```
   MYL9   TGFB1I1
   GPR174  CD3G    
   HAT1    ARL6IP6
```

The result should be:

```
   MYL9   TGFB1I1
   CD3G    GPR174      
   ARL6IP6  HAT1
```

The problem is I have a huge array of these and I am looking to see if there is af fast way of doing this instead of a for loop.

Comment: `t(apply(mydf, 1, sort))`?

Comment: With only two columns to sort, different solutions are available, like with example `DF= data.frame(V1=c("M","G","H"), V2=c("T","C","A"))` you can do `idx = which(DF[[1]] > DF[[2]]); DF[idx, 1:2] <- DF[idx, 2:1]` @MrFlick

Comment: @Frank It would be more useful to add that answer as a special case for one of the many existing duplicates.